# console.writeline within Task does not work

Tags: c#, multithreading, httptaskasynchandler

I am learning task aysny based programing and cannot get to make this code work. The console prints the message only once and then disappears.

if I remove the read line and run the program(not debug mode) the console just appears with message saying press a key to continue. When I debug and put the debugger in console.write then it works fine for some time and then the console window disappears and restarts again. If I use for loop <10000 instead of while  then also the behaviors is same

Could you please suggest what I am doing wrong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            multitasker();

        }

       static async void   multitasker()
        {
            Task task1 = new Task(PrintMessageA);
            task1.Start();
            await task1;            
        }

        static void PrintMessageA()
        {
          while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message from A");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your main thread does not block and thus is exiting immediately. You would have to go "await all the way" in a sense and await `multitasker` as well, but you can't actually do that as seen later.

So first you return a task in `multitasker`

```
static async Task multitasker()
{
    Task task1 = new Task(PrintMessageA);
    task1.Start();
    await task1;            
}
```

The problem is you cannot make `Main()` (the entry point) async, so instead you would need to block that thread by instead calling `Wait()` on the returned Task

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    multitasker().Wait();
}
```