# How to find out which Task has finished

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have an async code to upload all files in a directory to an API. It works fine but I would like to track which file has uploaded and would want to log, so that I can do some status check.

I have been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) and also [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete) . The first one creates explicit tasks for each file and the 2nd link, only talks about showing the number of tasks left. I, on the other hand, would like to find out which task has finished, print it to a log and carry on awaiting till there are no files to upload. I am using the Script component within SSIS to do this.

This is when 2 tasks are defined specifically for 2 files.

```
            Task<string> uploadCounterpartFileTask = UploadFiles(year, month, filename_counterparts, accesstoken, path);
            Task<string> uploadProductCategoryFileTask = UploadFiles(year, month, filename_productcategories, accesstoken, path);

            var allTasks = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> { uploadCounterpartFileTask, uploadProductCategoryFileTask };


            while (allTasks.Any())
            {
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task finished = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAny(allTasks);
                if (finished == uploadCounterpartFileTask)
                {
                    allTasks.Remove(uploadCounterpartFileTask);
                    var counterpartFile = await uploadCounterpartFileTask;
                }
                else if (finished == uploadProductCategoryFileTask)
                {
                    allTasks.Remove(uploadProductCategoryFileTask);
                    var productCategoriesFile = await uploadProductCategoryFileTask;
                }
            }
```

But I do not want to do that now as I would not know how many files would be in the directory

I would like to upload all files in a directory, something like this.:-

```
string[] fileSystemEntries = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path);

            var tasks = fileSystemEntries.OrderBy(s => s).Select(
            fileName => UploadFiles(year, month, Path.GetFileName(fileName), accesstoken, path));
            while (tasks.Any())
            {

                var finished = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAny(tasks);



                    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Script Task for uploading AVRO files", "File Uploaded" + finished.Result, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
                    tasks.Remove(finished);


            }
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Script Task for uploading AVRO files", "All Files Uploaded", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
```

I am using finished.Result because the documentation on MSDN states that Result gives the task that completed after whenAny. I know whenAny gives the first and therefore I am looping (similar to the examples on MSDN).

You see the Dts.Events.FireInformation as this is inside a script task within SSIS.

I would expect that it would say in the log something like.

File Uploaded: Counterparts.avro

File Uploaded: ProductCategorties.avro

File Uploaded: SomeOtherFile.avro

All Files uploaded.

But , though the file upload goes all right, none of the statements are printed.

How do I make them print? I just do not want to have a single notification for all files, I would really want to have a status of which file got uploaded.

EDIT: In response to one of the comments, here is the code for UploadFiles. Basically it uploads a file to an API and, per file involes 3 REST calls.

```
    private async Task<string> UploadFiles(string year, string month, string filename, string accesstoken, string path)
    {
        //Initial Put
        var method = new HttpMethod("PUT");
        string url = String.Format("https://someurl/part1/{0}/{1}/{2}?resource=file&recursive=True", year, month, filename);


        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url)
        {
            Content = null
        };

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);


        var initput = await client.SendAsync(request);

        //Append Data
        url = String.Format("https://someurl/part1/{0}/{1}/{2}?action=append&position=0", year, month, filename);

        string SourceFile = path;
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        string filenamefullyqualified = path + filename;
        Stream fs = System.IO.File.Open(filenamefullyqualified, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        content.Add(CreateFileContent(fs, filename, "text/plain"));

        method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

        request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url)
        {
            Content = content
        };

        //long filelength = new System.IO.FileInfo(filenamefullyqualified).Length;

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        long? position = request.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

        //Flush Data

        url = String.Format("https://someurl/part1/{0}/{1}/{2}?action=flush&position={3}", year, month, filename, position.ToString());

        request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url)
        {
            Content = null
        };

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);


        response = await client.SendAsync(request);


        return filename;

    }
```

EDIT 2 : In response to the comment. Please note that it is a sample code that I am trying, to demonstrate this problem.

```
    public async void Main()
    {
        bool fireAgain = true;
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888")
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                BypassProxyOnLocal = true
            },
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        };

        string year = "2019";
        string month = "02";
        string path = "D:\\SomeFolder\\AVRO\\";

        client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
        string resp = getBearerToken().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = ser.DeserializeObject(resp);
        Dictionary<string, object> BearerTokenDetails = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        BearerTokenDetails = (Dictionary<string, object>)(result);

        string accesstoken = BearerTokenDetails["access_token"].ToString();
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Script Task for uploading AVRO files", "Access Code: " + accesstoken, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);


        string[] fileSystemEntries = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path);

        var tasks = fileSystemEntries.OrderBy(s => s).Select(
        fileName => UploadFiles(year, month, Path.GetFileName(fileName), accesstoken, path));

        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Script Task for uploading AVRO files", "All Files Uploaded", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);


    }
```

You would see a getBearerToken method which I defined as async but later made it a Blocked call using GetResult as that needs to happen first. Also, point to note is- the first FireInfo that you see after the Bearer Token , only worked after I made it a blocking call (the GetResult does that as I read).

Comment: Please check the code in the second link you have given, it has your answer. There is a loop which checks the condition `tasks.Count != 0`, since inside the loop you keep removing the task as they finish and process them, the loop stops when the count goes to 0, i.e. all tasks have been processed.

Comment: But the dts.Events.FireInfo is within the loop and remove is after the Dts.events.FireInfo. Please note , that I have 2 Dts.Events.FireInfo. Perhaps, you looked at only the one outside, which is for all the files when they are done. There is also one, inside the loop.

Comment: What is the code of  the method `UploadFiles`?

Comment: If all you want to do is logging, assume that `UploadFile` returns a `Task<T>` object, you can use `ContinueWith` method, the delegate will be invoked as soon as `UploadFile` is finished.

Comment: @PeterBons: updated the question to include it.

Comment: Are you sure `FireInformation` works as expected?

Comment: @JohnWu: FireInformation works , at least for synchronous operations. Let me try to write to a log file and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `FireInformation` works as intended, your code can be greatly simplified.

You can log the completion per task inside `UploadFiles`:

```
private async Task<string> UploadFiles(string year, string month, string filename, string accesstoken, string path)
{
    // stuff


    response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    // Log task finished
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Script Task for uploading AVRO files", "File Uploaded" + filename, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);  

    return filename;
}
```

The end of the method is the moment the file has been uploaded and the task is finished. No need for a while loop and manually removing tasks from an array.

*It think you even do not need to return the filename anymore if it is only for the logging*

To log all completed message simply write a log file after `Task.WhenAll`:

```
        string[] fileSystemEntries = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path);

        var tasks = fileSystemEntries.OrderBy(s => s).Select(
        fileName => UploadFiles(year, month, Path.GetFileName(fileName), accesstoken, path));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Script Task for uploading AVRO files", "All Files Uploaded", string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
```

Now, since you are running in the console, you have two options, use `public async Task Main()` as the method signature (require c# 7.1, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main)) or change `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` to `Task.WaitAll(tasks);` otherwise the application won't wait for your code to finish and hence no output is shown.

Additionally an option is to add the line `Console.ReadKey();` at the very end of your `Main` method and wait for the output to show.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that as well but it just does not print. Therefore I was trying to print it outside just like the tutorial.  So, without debugging at any point: Nothing. And with debugging at "Wait All" : only File Uploaded: ProductCategorties.avro and All Files uploaded. Could it be because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331050/console-writeline-within-task-does-not-work ?

Comment: @SaugatMukherjee The second code snippet in my answer is contained in a method I assume, how is it called by your application?

Comment: This is called within the Main() method which is defined as async because there is an await i.e. it is within :  public async void Main(). Should I wrap it in some method and take it out , so that Main is not async ? sorry, but I am quite new to this async programming.

Comment: Edited the question to include that as well, including some information as well.

Comment: Thanks. That works with the printing within uploadFiles method. Thanks :). But the one in the main method , does not print. i.e. All Files Uploaded does not print.

Comment: @SaugatMukherjee maybe `Dts.Events.FireInformation` dooes not respond immediately. have you tried adding `Console.ReadKey();` as the last line in the Main method and wait a few secs after the last message is printed?

Comment: Sorry, must have missed something. It works. Super thanks :). Just wanted to make sure, I will read up though, but isn't await whenall  going to wait? what is await for then? But I will try to Google it anyways. Thanks for the help . I did this , as you mentioned : Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait()

Comment: await will not block the current thread, so other work could be done. There is a lot to talk about, I suggest starting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)